# My app doesn't appear in the AVD, after running from eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I created a small app in eclipse for android, and when I press "Run", a new AVD is created, eclipse tells me that the app was installed on the AVD, but I can't find it on the virtual device. Why can that be? Thanks

Comment: Did  you add a main activity in the manifest?

Comment: Do you have a main activity in the manifest with the LAUNCHER intent? also does the ADT plugin install and launch an activity for you?

Answer (score 5):

I think you probably forgot to add these lines in the manifest file. I had the same problem in an app and it showed that the app was installed, but could not find it in the emulator.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Also make sure you set up the target AVD from Run Configurations. Run->Run Configurations-> Target, then select the AVD from list, click Apply, then Ok. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

In 'Run Configurations', under the 'Target' tab, you can select the 'Always prompt to pick device' radio button.  Then when you go to run the app with the green go button at the top, you can choose from any device.  MaxPower47 solved this in the following thread:
[Can't run older Android targets in AVD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430819/cant-run-older-android-targets-in-avd)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the previously created avd and make a new one, launch it first and then run the app. I faced a similar problem a month ago and this worked for me, hope it does for you too. Probably a case of avd not registering with the adt plugin of eclipse and with two emulators running, the apk does not install properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an older AVD, it worked for me