# Can't run older Android targets in AVD

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to test an app in an AVD with Android 3.1 as the target but it is running terribly slow and doesn't seem to respond.  I created a new AVD with Android 2.1 as the target but this AVD does not show up in the run configurations in Eclipse even when refreshed and restarted.

Does anyone know why I cannot run older versions of Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found that the targetSdkVersion in the manifest file affects what shows up in the run configuration.  Setting the target selection mode to Manual in the run configuration should open a popup when you run it that lets you select any AVD, not just ones that meet the targetSdkVersion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the emulator RAM to 1024Mb.

Go go to AVD Manager click on the emulator and then edit. 
You should find Device ram size and set the new value and then "Edit AVD".